# React rendering a component triggers the onClick event?

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, components, mount

```
var CustomerTable = React.createClass({    
  addEmailButton: function(customerId) {
    console.log(customerId);
    return (
      <button onClick={console.log("clicked", customerId)}>X</button>
    )
  },

  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {
              this.state.customers.map(function(customer, i) {
                return (
                  <tr key={i}>
                    <td>{self.addEmailButton(customer['id'])}</td>
                  </tr>
                )
              })
            }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

When this component is rendered, the console.log call is executed without clicking any of the buttons.

I just want to call a method when a button is clicked, nothing really complicated.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to use `addEmailButton` as a closure for the `customerId`, but it doesn't help because it's the handler that needs the `customerId` argument, not the rendering of the button.

All you need is to `bind` the click event with the `customerId` argument:

```
var CustomerTable = React.createClass({    
  handleClick: function(customerId, event) {
    console.log("clicked", customerId);
  },
  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    return (
      <...>
        {
          this.state.customers.map(function(customer, i) {
            return (
              <tr key={i}>
                <td>
                  <button onClick={self.handleClick.bind(self, customer['id'])}>X</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            )
          })
        }
      <...>
    )
  }
});
```

Or, using ES6 you can use arrow functions instead of `self` and `bind`:

```
{
  this.state.customers.map((customer, i) => {
    return (
      <tr key={i}>
        <td>
          <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(customer['id'])}>X</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: you don't need use `self`, you can set `this` for `.map` across second argument `this.state.customers.map(function() {}, this)`

Comment: Yep, true, or you could use `bind`, but OP was using `self`; my main point was binding the click handler with `customerId` (which must be done with `bind` or arrow function).

Answer (score 1):

You should pass to `onClick` reference to function

```
<button onClick={() => console.log("clicked", customerId)}>X</button>
```

or if you don't use `ES2015` arrow function

```
<button onClick={function () { console.log("clicked", customerId) } }>X</button>
```

in your example you are passing to `onClick` `undefined`, because `console.log()` returns `undefined`, but not reference to function., `{}` in `JSX` context means that you can pass to it JS code which you want to execute.

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/36844/)

Comment: @Sergio Tapia could you give feedback?